# Guided Access App not available

Tags: ios, guided-access

I'm sometimes getting an error when starting my 'Guided Access' app which is locked down on the iPad using 'Apple Configurator'.

It mostly happens after a hard reset, but not always. The error on screen is:

**Guided Access App not available.**

There's also a suspicious looking console entry which says:

*Warning: |GuidedAccess|error| Springboard server could not disconnect from frontmost app message service gracefully: (null)*

I'm not getting stuck in the guided app like many other threads reference, I'm getting this when resetting the iPad. Tried google but found nothing

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?